# Why does VS Code C++ say path not specified?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-c++

Looking for help with this error message.
After installing the C++ extension for VS Code, installing MinGW-64, and setting the environment path variable, creating a simple hello world program I am getting the following peculiar error:

```
C:\Users\oscar\Documents\Labs>cd "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/binc/Users/oscar/OneDrive/Documents/test/" && g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld && "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/binc/Users/oscar/OneDrive/Documents/test/"helloworld
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Notes:
g++ version shows 8.1.0 and
using CodeRunner extension to run the code in the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by uninstalling and reinstalling everything